# Disable submit button until textarea ihas more than 100 chars

Tags: php, javascript

How can I disable the submit button until the chars of a textarea are more than 100 chars?

This is a code used to check if the user has selected to upload an image. Please inform me how should I name my textarea and guide me through the installation of it.

```
$(function() {
   $('form').submit(function() {
      if(!$("form input[type=file]").val()) {
         alert('You must select a file!');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about a text area or file input? Everyone has been answering in regard to a textarea.

Answer (score 5):

First of, make the submit button disabled, eg.

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="submitid" />
```

Next you should write a function that will count the length of the textarea while the user is writing, this could be done by using the keyup function in jQuery or onkeyup in plain Javascript.
Example in jQuery:

```
$("#textareaid").keyup(function () {
  if((this).val().length > 100) {
    $("#submitid").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#submitid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

*Note: code not tested.*

SetInterval approach:

```
setInterval(function () {
  if($("#textareaId").val().length > 100) {
    $("#submitid").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#submitid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}, 500); //Runs every 0.5s
```

Full size example:

```
<form>
  <textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submitId" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function () {
    if($("#textareaId").val().length > 100) {
      $("#submitId").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#submitId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }, 500); //Runs every 0.5s
</script>
```

Comment: Now it will, forgot to add id attribute to the input tag.

Comment: What if a user just paste some information? My concern is that this form will be used for paste content...

Comment: @punkis If your concern is that your users use the copy'n'paste approach using the mouse, you should use the setInterval approach.

Comment: Thank you I will test it and return for the result. One small question, speaking for the SetInterval approach that I will use, how does the code understands the presence of the textarea?

Comment: I have added a fullsize example of the code, basically it looks for an element with the id "textareaId", checks if it contains more than 100 characters, if it does enable the element with the id "submitId".

Comment: @Mads Madsen I have tried your code as is in a new php and html file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">` above them but it didn't work...

Comment: There is missing a '$' infront of ("#textareaId"), add that and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can either update the status of the submit button every time the data within the text area is changed, however this can be problematic as each browser has different events for textareas (in javascript)

A common way to do it is by setting an interval to check the submit box, then based on that decide the boolean value for the button. For instance

```
window.setInterval(function(){ $('#submitBtn').disabled =  $("#textArea").val().length < 100 }, 100);
```

(Code not tested)

Comment: There is no need for *setInteral()* at all, just use keyup on the textarea (or some parent element).

Comment: keyup won't always be sucessfull, what if they right click and paste in information.

Answer (score -1):

Users much prefer it if the number of characters in textarea is validated on submit. If it's less than 100, cancel the submit and give the user an error message saying why. Presumably there's a hint on the page so the user should know of the 100 character criterion and how many characters they've entered.

If you *really* want the button disabled, then disable it using script when the page loads. Use a key-up listener to count the characters in the textarea and enable the submit button if there's more than 100. You may need to listed to other events too so if the user changes the text by dragging or paste, then the submit button's disabled property is updated appropriately.

Comment: Doesn't handle all events required, -1

Comment: @user551841 - yes, which is why validating on submit is a much better option and the recommended approach.

Answer (score -1):

Building on Minitech's rather terse answer:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        if(!$("form input[type=file]").val()) {
            alert('You must select a file!');
            return false;
        }

        if($("#theTextArea").val().length <= 100) {
            alert("You must enter more than 100 characters!");
            return false;
        }
   });
});
```

Just replace `theTextArea` with the id of the specific textarea you want to test

Comment: What about in my case that is a textarea as correctly added in the code and a submit button ?

Comment: without really know what your HTML code is, that's hard to say - but this function reacts to the forms submit event... so it won't let the person submit (although, the button is not visibly disabled)

Comment: Your text says "textaera" but your code says `form input[type=file]`

Comment: Will this work on a right click -> paste information? Please give me some instructions on how to add this code to my existing file.

Comment: @Punkis - if you're talking about a file input (per your code) you can't paste into it, you can **only** use the file browser. If you are talking about a textarea (per your text), then just validate on submit. Until then, the number of characters is irrelevant.

Comment: @Punkis - I'm just adding in the textarea length check after the file check you've already done - you should just need to copy this new code into the same place where you already have the check for the file input.